# PHP, Debian Linux, and SOAP

Tags: php, soap, debian

I ran into a very interesting problem today.  PHP 7.2 SoapClient version 1.2 (just with Cache mode disabled) was unable to load up a remote WSDL but was able to use the Soap listener service at the same base URL (even in the same directory).  Any ideas at all? I just copied the WSDL locally as a workaround but this isn't a long term solution.

Thanks!

Comment: what does "unable to" mean exactly? Did you get any kind of error, or specific unexpected behaviour? Where is your code? Was this just a temporary problem - it isn't clear if it persists or was just in the morning you mentioned?

Comment: I get the soap fault error:  "Could not connect to host"  This also now also applies to localhost version of the WSDL.  I've disabled SOAP caching and tried different domain name aliases for the localhost to no avail.